# How can i send AWS SNS HTTP dynamically to certain subscribers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am sending many messages but the subscribers change very often (per message), how can can i choose my specific subscribers on every message? the number of possibilities is too much to create topic to each combination.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A message is delivered to all subscribers of the SNS topic.

> Once you subscribe an endpoint to a topic and the subscription is
>   confirmed, the endpoint will receive all messages published to that
>   topic. [Source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SubscribeTopic.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the endpoints yourself on the back end. You then publish to an individual endpoint. For large groups you will have to build in flood protection.